# What is the industrial method for extracting caffeine to make decaf?

Tags: extraction, chemistry, decaffeinated

Is this a solvent extraction method? If so what solvent is used and if it is organic, do the manufacturers verify elimination of a certain percentage of residual solvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caffeine is mostly extracted by utilizing very safe processes. Some of them, such as Swiss water, is not even really a chemical process.

Please see the following relevant discussions:

- [Of the various methods of decaffeinating coffee, which is the safest?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/208/of-the-various-methods-of-decaffeinating-coffee-which-is-the-safest)
- [Which decaffeination process changes the flavor of the coffee the least?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/which-decaffeination-process-changes-the-flavor-of-the-coffee-the-least)
- [How is decaffeinated coffee made?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-is-decaffeinated-coffee-made)
- [How are caffeine pills made?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/how-are-caffeine-pills-made)

Also, you may want to see this answer to watch an animation of common Swiss water process:

- [Decaf coffee, how to make our own](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/decaf-coffee-how-to-make-our-own)

Comment: Please don't answer using links only. In this case, it'd be better to elaborate a bit on each method or to close as a duplicate of one of them.

Comment: @JJJ, thanks for the comment. I was about to mark it as duplicate. Then, I realized that relevant answers are a bit scattered. Then, compiled previous answers as I couldn't refer many of them as duplicates. I'll pay more attention.